# REST filters only firing when I have a param set

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, filters, rest-api

I'm trying to use a REST filter to require a certain parameter is set.

Using custom taxonomies and custom posts I've been able to make it so when I request

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/car?visible_to=123
```

That the only `Car`s that come back are ones with a `visible_to` taxonomy of 123.

However when someone asks for

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/car
```

I want to throw an error, saying that ?visible_to needs to be set.

I've tried hooking into `rest_index`, `rest_pre_dispatch`, and some others. Each only fires when I have `?visible_to` set in the URL, without them the hooks don't fire.

For example, I would expect this to fire on every REST request

```
add_filter( 'rest_pre_dispatch','to_limit_access', 1, 3);

function to_limit_access($args, $request, $context) {
  return new WP_Error( 'rest_disabled', __( 'The REST API is disabled on this site.' ), array( 'status' => 404 ) );
}
```

But it will only return a WP_Error on

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/car?visible_to=123
```

Both

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/car
```

And

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/car/6
```

Run without that filter being hit.

Can someone explain why this would be the case and what I can do to avoid it?

I've also tried specific filters like `rest_prepare_car` but I couldn't get it to fire at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a parameter to be required for a post type's REST API endpoint you can use the [`rest_{$this->post_type}_collection_params`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_collection_params/) filter to filter the [`$args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments) of the `GET` endpoint:

```
add_filter(
    'rest_car_collection_params',
    function( array $query_params ) {
        $query_params['visible_to']['required'] = true;
        
        return $query_params;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In turns out we had a caching plugin enabled that was getting in the way of some requests but not others, leading to this inconsistency.